# Android Studio Stop Sound

Tags: java, android, audio, methods, pause

thats my first question here.
I hope i get a solution.
I coded a soundboard app and i want that if i click the button a sound play.
i got that easily.
the next point is that i want to if i click another button the other sound **stop**.
i hope you understand. i tried a lot with .stop or .pause...

thats my java code on this page:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public void stop(){

    }


    Button btone1,btone2,btone3,btone4,btone5,btone6,btone7,btone8,btone9,btone10,btone11,btone12;

    @Nullable
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout,container, false);




        btone1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone1);
        final MediaPlayer mpone1 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone1.start();
            }
        });
        


        btone2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone2);
        final MediaPlayer mpone2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone2);
        btone2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone2.start();
            }
        });


        btone3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone3);
        final MediaPlayer mpone3 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone2);
        btone3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone3.start();
            }
        });


        btone4 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone4);
        final MediaPlayer mpone4 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone4.start();
            }
        });


        btone5 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone5);
        final MediaPlayer mpone5 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone5.start();
            }
        });


        btone6 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone6);
        final MediaPlayer mpone6 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone6.start();
            }
        });


        btone7 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone7);
        final MediaPlayer mpone7 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone7.start();
            }
        });


        btone8 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone8);
        final MediaPlayer mpone8 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone8.start();
            }
        });


        btone9 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone9);
        final MediaPlayer mpone9 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone9.start();
            }
        });


        btone10 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone10);
        final MediaPlayer mpone10 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone10.start();
            }
        });


        btone11 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone11);
        final MediaPlayer mpone11 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone11.start();
            }
        });

        btone12 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btone12);
        final MediaPlayer mpone12 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sone1);
        btone12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mpone12.start();
            }
        });

        ////




        return rootView;



        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single MediaPlayer object instead of creating multiple ones

then stop using this code

```
private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
       }
    }
```